# Finding search items in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am currently working on a project that outputs to a JTextArea, I have been given the following specifications:

- The search being case insensitive;
- The search starting from cursor position (I currently do not have the cursor visible, and do not know how to do this - so if someone can help me out here as well I would be grateful);
- And, after the search has been completed, and the user clicks anywhere on the text area the highlight on the search items will be removed.

I currently have this code for "Find" action:

```
        String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Find What?");
        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.orange);

        int offset = outputArea.getText().indexOf(search);
        int length = search.length();

        while (offset != -1) {
            try {
                outputArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = outputArea.getText().indexOf(search, offset + 1);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                System.err.println("An error occured, please try again");
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your question / problem?

Comment: How do I make the search case insensitive?
How do I make search start from cursor position?
And how do I make sure that after the search has been completed, and the user clicks anywhere on the text area the highlight on the search items will be removed?

Answer (score 1):

`outputArea.getText().toLowerCase()` 
and 
`search.toLowerCase()`will help with the case insensitive searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outputArea.getCaretPosition()` to get the index of the cursor over the String of the model.

You can then use `text.substring(caretPos, text.length()).indexOf(searchTerm)` to do the searching.